# Seeking rationale for Hadamard's finite part of a divergent integral

Tags: distribution-theory, integration

I have a problem justifying the throwing away the divergent term in order to obtain Hadamard's finite part. I find this step to be highly unusual and it is not obvious to me how the resulting expression can be valid. I'd appreciate, if possible, intuitive arguments -- I assume there are some. Its not the mathematics that I have problems with at this stage. Its the intuition.

For example (taken from the Wikipedia [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_finite_part)) the finite part of the following integral 
$$
\int_a^b \frac{f(t)}{(t-x)^2}\, dt = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \left\{ \int_a^{x-\varepsilon}\frac{f(t)}{(t-x)^2}\,dt + \int_{x+\varepsilon}^b\frac{f(t)}{(t-x)^2}\,dt -\frac{2f(x)}{\varepsilon}\right\}
$$
involves throwing away the term $\frac{2f(x)}{\varepsilon}$. I find it hard to justify this step especially when the term is neither finite nor negligible.

Comment: This Q migrated to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/67751/rationale-for-hadamards-finite-part-of-a-divergent-integral.